# How to check application is reading from Secondary Node in MongodB?

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

I have a 3 member replica set. Read preference is set as "Secondary Preferred" How to check application is reading from Secondary Node in MongodB? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can configure profiling. For that you need to start your mongodb servers with option `--profile 2` and configure log file. It'll log all queries. 
After that you can read log for each instance db. Simple example:

```
db.your_collection.profile.find({ns: "name_your_db.your_collection"})
```

Secondly you can use `mongotop`. You need to start it for each mongodb server.
For example:

```
mongotop -h server_ip:server_port seconds
mongotop -h 127.0.0.1:27017 5
```

It'll print every specified period of time log, where you can read how much time for read or write is taken for each collection.

Answer (score 0):

Other means of determining whether queries are sent to secondaries:

- Enable command logging in the driver, which should tell you which server each command was sent to.
- Inspect server logs for connections being made or not made, then set minimum connection pool size to 0 so that a connection is only made when needed for a query, then run some queries.